# ¿Se puede mantener el correo en Godaddy y la web en Google Cloud Computing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, godaddy

Tengo un dominio en Godaddy, ahí administramos nuestros correos de la empresa y hasta ahora la pagina web y un sistema interno de administración, queremos pasar la web y el sistema a una instancia de Google Cloud Computing, sabemos como cambiar los NameServers de Godaddy para pasar a Google tal como lo indica la siguiente pagina https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart. Nuestra duda es; ¿si al cambiar los Nameservers seguirá funcionando el correo con Godaddy? Nosotros queremos que siga siendo así. ¿Se debería seguir algún paso extra para el correo después de cambiar los Nameservers?

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿GCC da servicio de Email, al estilo GSuite por ejemplo? Yo supongo que sí, porque GCC es un servicio mucho más avanzado que GSuite [¿?]. Hago la pregunta porque si es así estarías renunciando a una ventaja muy interesante. Al menos con GSuite puedes configurar tus direcciones de email personalizadas (`@tudominio.com`) y usarlas con todas las ventajas de Google (en mi caso los spams se vieron reducidos a casi cero, cuando anteriormente estaba casi a punto de dejar de usar el email personalizado porque los filtros del hosting eran malísimos).

Comment: GCC tiene bloqueados los puertos para email, se tiene que usar GSuite si quieres el correo.

Comment: Algún experto en GCC podrá confirmarlo con mayor seguridad, no creo que haya problemas. Lo que no sé exactamente es si vas a tener que configurar algún registro `MX` que apunte desde GCC a GoDaddy, o si, omitiendo configuraciones de registros `MX` asumirá que todo lo relativo al email lo manejará GoDaddy. Es cuestión de probar o, preguntar al servicio técnico de GoDaddy y/o GCC para actuar con certeza.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que diferenciar:
- GCP es un servicio orientado a PaaS e IaaS principalmente, entre otros, no un servicio de hosting.
- Un dominio es solo una forma de acceso, tomando eso en cuenta te dejo lo siguiente:

1. No puedes migrar de manera transparente un servicio de mail, con cualquier proveedor a un servidor de aplicaciones, tendrías que tener todo el software de emailing instalado en una máquina virtual ( Compute Engine ), y dar salida a los puertos correspondientes por reglas de firewall.
2. La opción para realizar esa migración de forma correcta, es utilizar el servicio de GSuite, ellos te dirán como conservar tu dominio, utilizando google users, aprovechando la Gsuite y a la vez permitiendote usar google auth, con dichas cuentas.